# Notification firing late

Tags: android

I have a notification service but it seems that the notifications are getting fired one minute or so late every time. Please help me out here. Below is the code from my service class. Also notice if there are multiple notifications, few are getting missed. I mean no alarms or notification.

```
public class ReminderService extends WakeReminderIntentService {
AlertDialog alertDialog;
int currentVolume;
public ReminderService() {
    super("ReminderService");
}

@Override
void doReminderWork(Intent intent) {

    Log.d("ReminderService", "alarm");
    Long rowId = intent.getExtras().getLong(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID);


    NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent i = new Intent(this, ReminderShowActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.putExtra(RemindersDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    Notification note = builder.setContentIntent(pi)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.stat_sys_warning).setTicker("New Alert Reminder")
            .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle("Alert from Call-You-Back")
            .setContentText("Click Me Respond !!").build();
    builder.setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000});


    note.sound =    Uri.parse("android.resource://com.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/raw/sound");
    note.vibrate=new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 };
    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    int id = (int) ((long) rowId);
    mgr.notify(id, note);

}
```

Comment: How are you documenting that the notifications are late?

Comment: i am checking it in real device as well as in logcat. Both pc and mobile are correct to seconds in date time